# LDAP connect failed: invalid server address

Tags: django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

I am using the django_python3_ldap plugin to authenticate logins on my django application (in production) through an ldap server. For some reason it all the sudden doesn't like my server address , even though it is correct and can connect to the same address on my workstation.

I get this wsgi error

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 6439] LDAP connect failed: invalid server address
```

I have tried enabling `httpd_can_connect_ldap` to on,  but that didn't fix the problem.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason it didn't like the url anymore, so i changed it to the ip address instead and set 
`LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS` in my settings.py to `False` and it worked again.